# What ports/services needs to be opened for PowerShell Active Directory to function?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, port

So far, I've tried opening port 9389 and ADWS is running on the remote server... and no luck...

The command:

```
$credential = Get-Credential # Feed it the Foreign Dommain\Username + Password
Get-ADUser 'someUser' -Server some.remote.server.com -Credential $credential
```

Here's the error:

```
Get-ADUser : Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server does
not exist, it is currently dow does not have the Active Directory Web Services
running.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADUser 'someUser' -Server some.remote.server.com -Credential $credential
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (e313681:ADUser) [Get-ADUser], ADServerDownException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

I can ping this machine and remote to it, but I can't query it with PowerShell.

I've checked that ADWS is running on the domain controller... out of ideas here - did I miss a port or something?

Comment: [Link on Active Directory necessary ports](http://techgenix.com/whatallportsarerrequiredbydomaincontrollersandclientcomputers/).  Also, [ensure that ADWS is running](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391908(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: [Related](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772723.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Really hope you got this problem solved after over 2.5 years. Got here through Google as I was looking for my own problem. Just dropping the information here for others that might hit this page.

Powershell is using ADWS and the port being used is 9389.

In the end for me it was the Windows Firewall blocking this port. For anyone in the same situation, check %SystemRoot%\System32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log for drops to the IP of the AD controller you are trying to connect to.